# How can can I put a Samsung RS275 fridge in defrost mode?

Tags: refrigerator

I have been trying to put this refrigerator in forced defrost, but I can't seem to find the right button combination to do so.

Anyone know?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "how do I operate my fridge?" is [not on topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This most certainly has a valid question regarding a complicated operation, that is not well defined in the basic instruction manual.  We answer questions here that are about what tool is this or how to find a lightbulb.  We should certainly help someone that has a problem with an appliance...after all it was not a question like , "how do I make my oven hot?"

Comment: Contact Samsung's customer service department with a question regarding how to operate their products.

Comment: Anyone looking at the replies can see that this is not an obvious question, requiring access to the service manual, which was not easy to find either. As per contacting the vendor… that applies to nearly *every* StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help, or have you already tried these buttons?

https://samsung.manymanuals.com/fridges/rs275/user-manual-30759

[image]

Comment: You didn't add the information for Rohit. You added it because it makes good sense and network guidelines require it. Links are not answers.

Comment: Thank you @RohitGupta — very helpful. I will try this later tonight, I could not find this service manual in my searches.

Comment: Thanks you @Huesmann — you found the service manual I could not locate. That key sequence worked!

Answer (score 1):

To defrost a Samsung refrigerator, press and hold the ‘Power Freeze’ and ‘Fridge’ buttons simultaneously for 8 to 10 seconds. When you hear a beep, release the buttons and the refrigerator defrost will begin to defrost. On some models, you may need to turn off the ‘Lock’ button first by pressing it for three seconds. Additionally, pressing the ‘Lighting’ button after holding down the other two buttons may also initiate defrosting.

Here is a good video of a number of features.  The forced defrost is explaned @ the 6:50 mark.

[Samsung features](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OmI9wAVH5s)

Comment: Was so easy on the older fridges.  Want to defrost, just unplug.

Comment: @crip659 that still works if you have time for it. The "forcing" engages the built-in heating elements which speed the process up, assuming they are working - of course, if they are working, you shouldn't have to "force" it as it's supposed to "auto-defrost" so forcing it may not help anyway...